# Custom paint rounded triangle

Tags: android, ios, flutter

Consider:

[image: Expected rounded triangle]

How can I make a rounded triangle like in the picture (with border)?

I write the following, but it looks strange, and the border been clipped. I want to keep.

[image: Clipped rounded triangle]

```
ClipPath(
  clipper: MyLeftArrowClipper(),
  child: Container(
    // width: 100,
    // height: 50,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.amber, border: Border.all()),
    child: Text('time'),
  ),
),
```

```
class MyLeftArrowClipper extends CustomClipper<Path> {
  @override
  Path getClip(Size size) {
    printDebug('size= $size');
    var firstOffset = Offset(0, size.height * 0.5);
    var secondPoint = Offset(size.width * 0.15, 0);
    var right1 = Offset(size.width, 0);
    var right2 = Offset(size.width, size.height);
    var left1 = Offset(size.width * 0.15, size.height);
    var path = Path()
      ..moveTo(firstOffset.dx, firstOffset.dy)
      ..lineTo(secondPoint.dx, secondPoint.dy)
      ..lineTo(right1.dx, right1.dy)
      ..lineTo(right2.dx, right2.dy)
      ..lineTo(left1.dx, left1.dy)
      ..lineTo(firstOffset.dx, firstOffset.dy)
      ..close();

    return path;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldReclip(covariant CustomClipper<Path> oldClipper) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: see [roundPolygon](https://gist.github.com/pskink/adf730167a48b750a81f1dd197309312#file-round_polygon-dart-L24)

Comment: Re *"I want to keep"*: Want to keep what?